# Do I need to dispose the graphic context returned from Component.getGraphics()?

Tags: java, awt

I have learned that you need to call dispose() on Graphics objects that you have created when you are done using them. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out from the API documentation when Graphics objects are created.

Obviously when a Graphics object is passed into a callback, then I haven't created it, and shouldn't dispose of it (or modify it in any other way from what I've heard), and if I call Graphics.create(), then I am creating it and I should dispose of it.

But what about when I call Component.getGraphics()? Is this creating a new Graphics2D object that I am responsible for disposing, or is it returning a reference to an existing object that I shouldn't modify? The documentation doesn't say either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only dispose Graphics objects that you explicitly create. So in your example you would not be calling dispose on the object you get back from Component.getGraphics(), unless its documentation explicitly states that the object was created for you.

Comment: What really got me confused was BufferedImage. It has a method called createGraphics() whose name hints that I would need to call dispose. But it has another method named getGraphics() which returns the same result as createGraphics(), but doesn't say anything about who owns the returned value, and made me start questioning who owns the returned value from Component.getGraphics().

Comment: Yea I know what you mean. Java doesn't really have a naming standard or convention when it comes to indicating returned resources which will require special handling by the caller. Mainly because automatic GC gives so much cover to memory mgmt. It's probably best to consult the Javadoc when in doubt, and sometimes even the code.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question for me. So was the result of getGraphics "created for me"? Or the answer to that can be different depending on the context?